# Square Register API - Developer in non-enabled country

Tags: square-connect

I am developing with the Square Register API.
My developer is based in India.

I get this error:

> "User not activated. The logged-in account cannot take credit card
>   payments. This could be because the account is from a country where
>   Square does not process payments

Is there any way to enable my developer in India to work with the Register API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the Point of Sale API can only take card payments in supported countries (i.e., UK, US, CA, JP, AU).

You have two options:

1. Specify a non-card tender type (E.g., Cash, Other) if the account is not in a supported country.
2. If you have a square account set up in one of the above countries that can take payments, you can add your developer as an employee (With mobile point of sale access turned on).  This will allow them to login with their own credentials and use your square account for development.

[Square employee management support center article.](https://squareup.com/help/us/en/article/5591-employee-management)

Comment: thanks,,, I went for option 1 as it served my purpose.